# Results differ 'without changing anything'

Tags: r

The following code tries to build a simple binary tree. A non-leaf node contains a left child 'Lchild' and a right child 'Rchild'. A leaf node contains nothing. The problem of this code is that, adding a call of the variable 'root' but without changing anything (details refer to comment in the code) will change the result of 'BiTree'. The code is executable. The result `BiTree[[2]]` differs between calling or without calling of 'root'.

```
## rm(list=ls()) ## ANTI-SOCIAL
set.seed(1234)

##this part generate dataset
numVar <- 40  ##number of variables
numSamples <- 400  ##number of samples
Class <- sample(c(0,1), replace = 1, numSamples)  ##categorical outcome as '0' or '1'
predictor <- matrix( sample(c(-1,0,1), replace=1, numSamples*numVar), ncol=numVar)
data <- data.frame(predictor, Class)

##BiTree is a list storing a nodes information, reprenting a tree, defined as global
BiTree <- array( list(NULL), dim = 15 )

##set i as global variable to store the ID of each node on the tree, defiend as global
i <- 1

##function to create a tree
##parameter 'root' is the ID of root node for each sub-tree
createTree <- function( data, root )
{
   ##stop grow the sub-tree if data size is smaller than 10
   if( (nrow(data) <= 10 ) )  { i <<- i + 1; return(); }

   ##seperate the data into two parts to grow left-sub-tree and right-sub-tree
   index.P1 <- 1:floor( nrow( data )/2 )
   index.P2 <- !index.P1
   data.P1 <- data[ index.P1,  ]
   data.P2 <- data[ index.P2,  ]

   ##NOTE HERE: result will differ with or without execute any of the following call of root
   ##root
   ##cat(root)
   ##print(root)

   ##i records the ID of node in the tree. it increments after one new node is added to     the tree
   i <<- i + 1

   ##record node ID for left child of the root
   BiTree[[ root ]]$Lchild <<- i

   ##create left branch
   createTree( data.P1, i )

   ##record node ID for right child of the root
   BiTree[[ root ]]$Rchild <<- i

   ##create right branch
   createTree( data.P2, i )
}

createTree( data, 1 )

##look at the second node on the tree, which will differ
(BiTree[[2]])
```

Comment: You are using global variables - a shortcut to debugging hell...

Comment: @James yes I use global variables

Comment: @joran yes they are not necessary. But the question still remains

Comment: It's because of the delayed evaluation of `root`. The lines you commented out force the evaluation of `root`. Try adding `force(root)` as the first line of the function. This is a pretty good example why designing your code to rely on `<<-` can be a bad idea.

Comment: @joran This explains. But why there is delay of evaluation in this situation? How to avoid that?

Comment: Just what I said: `force()` is specifically to force evaluation. You increment `i` just before the assignment using `root` as an index. `root` was passed as a promise, pointing to the value of `i` in the calling environment. But you change the value of `i` before the value of `root` is actually needed. That means that when `root` is finally evaluated, you've altered the underlying value of `i`.